# How to set dynamic hotspot for 360 image with unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, hotspot, 360-virtual-reality, 360-panorama

I am trying to build a visitors tour with `Unity 3D`.  I have panaromic picture of bedrooms within an hotel and I would like to add points (hot spots) to my pictures that leads to another picture.

The problem is that I want to add this point dynamically via a backend, and I can't find a way to achieve that in `Unity`.

Comment: Enlighten us about what you tried thus-far by editing it into your question and not in comments!... its called "showing effort" and is a good medicine against down-voters. Also, on your quest to solve it by explaining you might end-up getting errors... that's where SO is at your service to help you with!

Comment: I can't find solution about it that is why i didnt post anything

Comment: any idea how to solve it now please ??

Comment: @Hoby please check my attempt to answer this question. If something is not clear let me know and I will try to help.

Comment: Please show an example of what you want.

Comment: @Hoby This question is far to broad and I would immediately mark it as `offtopic - 
Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.` if the bounty wouldn't hinder me ...

Answer (score 2):

I will try to answer this question.

Unity has a XYZ coordinate system that can be translated to real world. I would measure real distances to these points (from the center where you took your picture) in your location/room and send these coordinates via backend to Unity3D client.

In Unity you can create `Vector3` positions or directions based on coordinates you sent before. Use these positions/directions to instantiate 'hotspots' objects prefabs in right positions and directions. It might be necessary to adjust the scale/units to get the right result.

Once you have your 'hotspot' objects in place add a script to them that will load new scene (on click) with another location/image and repeat the process.

This is a very brief suggestion on how to do it. The code would be quite simple.